# Thumbnails com NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, thumbnail

Como posso gerar *thumbnails* de imagens que recebo no formato base64 com NodeJS? Atualmente salvo somente a original, porém gostaria de criar o *thumb* de cada uma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de algumas tentativas, utilizando o módulo [SHARP](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) consegui criar os *thumbnails*, utilizando o resize.